# test of equal predictive accuracy of forecasts for multiple nested models in R

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, cross-validation, arima

an out-of-sample forecast experiment (time series cross validation with a fixed rolling window size) using various models are applied. Suppose I have multiple forecasts from different models (LASSO,RR,elastic net) and in total 11 models. Since some models are restricted versions of one another (elastic net – LASSO), we´re dealing with nested models. In addition there are 6 forecasting horizons (h=1,3,6,9,12,24) and 3 samples [1x full sample, 2x subsamples]. Applying a test of equal forecast accuracy of each forecast against a benchmark, means that 198 tests have to be applied.

In general I want to compare the accuracy of forecasts produced from distinct models. Therefore I wish to test equal predictive accuracy of forecasts, which means that I´m more interested how well a model approximates the data.
Nullhypothesis: e.g. testing whether forecasts produced by RW are not better than forecasts from the distinct models or equivalently test the null hypothesis that “the benchmark is not inferior to any alternative forecast”

Which test can you recommend me? How can it be implemented in R for a simple example (2 forecasts from 2 models and a benchmark) as the following?:

```
library(forecast)
#time series
y1 = 2+ 0.15*(1:20) + rnorm(20,2)
y2 = y1[20]+ 0.3*(1:30) + rnorm(30,2)
y =  as.ts(c(y1,y2))
#10obs in out-of-sample; 40 obs in-sample
ntest <- 10
ntrain <- length(y)-ntest
#functions
fnaive <- function(x,h){naive(x,h=h)}
farima <- function(x,h){forecast(auto.arima(x,ic="aic",test=c("adf"),seasonal=FALSE, 
                                stepwise=FALSE, approximation = FALSE,
                                method=c("ML")),h=h)}
fets <- function(x,h){forecast(ets(x,model="ANN",alpha=NULL,
                       use.initial.values=FALSE),h=h)}
#forecast errors
e <- tsCV(y,fnaive,h = 24)
e1 <- tsCV(y,farima,h = 24,window=40)
e2 <- tsCV(y,fets,h = 24,window=40)

#out-of-sample error RW h=1
eRW1 <- e[-(1:ntrain),1]
#h=3
eRW3 <- e[-(1:ntrain),3]
.
.
#out-of-sample error ARIMA
earima1 <- e1[-(1:ntrain),1]
earima3 <- e1[-(1:ntrain),3]
.
.
```

Comment: The tests have quite different null hypotheses. I think the Clark & West test assumes perfect estimation precision, something that is unrealistic in practice. Diebold-Mariano test does not. What null hypothesis are you interested in precisely? Also, do you wish to test equal predictive accuracy of models or of forecasts? See Diebold ["Comparing Predictive Accuracy, Twenty Years Later: A Personal Perspective on the Use and Abuse of Diebold–Mariano Tests"](https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07350015.2014.983236) (2015) for a good discussion of the issues.

Comment: Question is edited. I wish to test equal predictive accuracy of forecasts from distinct models and  null hypothesis: e.g. the benchmark (RW) is not inferior to any alternative forecast.

Comment: You take either models or forecasts as primitives. If you take forecasts, it does not matter what models produced them and whether they were nested. That information can be ignored.

Comment: Yeah that sounds reasonable.I´ll take forecasts as primitives. How would you proceed? Which test is appropiate/useful in my case?